# cfloop index output in function call

Tags: coldfusion, cfloop

I have a loop which I need to add in the index to a function call. How can I do this?

Here is what I tried but it fails

```
<cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#arrayLen(test)#">
    #session_ID & i &.getSessionCount()#
</cfloop>
```

The index of the loop should output so that each iteration of the loop the line would look like this:

```
#session_ID1.getSessionCount()#
#session_ID2.getSessionCount()#
#session_ID3.getSessionCount()#
#session_ID4.getSessionCount()#
```

and so on.

Comment: Can you expand on using evaluate?

Comment: @Kevin B this seems to be giving me the correct output now: #evaluate("session_ID" & i).getSessionCount()# thank you i will go with this for now.

Comment: in the past i've used evaluate for things like this, but i read a post on here a while back about how you should avoid using it! if you check this page 'Avoiding the Evaluate function' http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec09d55-7fdf.html it gives you alternatives

Comment: Using `evaluate()` is unnecessary here, and is generally considered poor practice in general.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If one needs to create a variable name dynamically, then use associative array notation rather than dot notation, and reference the variable via the scope that it's in. EG:

```
<cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#arrayLen(test)#">
    <cfset result = variables["session_ID" & i].getSessionCount()>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: After so more reading and looking at Adam's example using the associative array notation i have gone with this. Thanks guys, i'm putting this down to learning something else new today.